# Programmatically check if android device has Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services

Currently there are some devices that doesn't have Google Play (Huawei Devices), is there a way for me to check programmatically if the device doesn't have one? I wanted to use the in-app-update feature: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates and check if the device has a Google PlayStore first.

What I have tried so far: using `Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)` but you need to start the activity first to confirm it exists? I'd like to know if there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the package `com.android.vending` exists or not

```java
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        return packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).enabled;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can do like this in your activity

```java
if(isPackageInstalled("com.android.vending", getPackageManager())){ 

   // play store is installed

}else{ 

   // play store is not installed

}
```

Comment: what different between if and else?

Answer (score 9):

**You can use the following code to check whether the android device has Google Play:**

```
boolean flag = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
```

If `flag == true`, then GMS is enable in device.

If `flag == false`, then GMS is disable in device.

Comment: is this code blocking and need another thread or we can use that code on the main thread?

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery Can be used on main thread, although the best practice is to avoid calling on main thread anything that specifically does not need to run on main thread.